# Proof of Matrix Cross-Multiplication Distributive Property

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, associativity

I am trying to prove that $A\times(B+C)=A \times B + A \times C.$

I have managed to prove this by finding the LHS  $$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1}\\a_{2}\\a_{3}
\end{pmatrix} × \begin{pmatrix}
b_{1}+c_{1} \\b_{2}+c_{2}\\b_{3}+c_{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$
then finding the RHS $$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1}\\a_{2}\\a_{3}
\end{pmatrix} × \begin{pmatrix}
b_{1} \\b_{2}\\b_{3}
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} \\a_{2}\\a_{3}
\end{pmatrix}× \begin{pmatrix}
c_{1} \\c_{2}\\c_{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$and equating LHS = RHS.

However I need to prove the equation directly from the LHS rather than finding the RHS and equating (possibly using separate matrix properties). I.E. I need to continue proving from \begin{pmatrix}
a_{2}b_{3}+a_{2}c_{3} - a_{3}b_{2} - a_{3}c_{2} \\a_{3}b_{1} + a_{3}c_{1} - a_{1}b_{3}-a_{1}c_{3}\\a_{1}b_{2}+a_{1}c_{2} -a_{2}b_{1}-a_{2}c_{1}
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Don’t switch in and out of MathJax like that. `$A\times (B+C)=…$` is fine.

Comment: Also, you can get indexes with the `$a_{1}$` rendered as $a_1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that: $$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{2}b_{3}+a_{2}c_{3} - a_{3}b_{2} - a_{3}c_{2} \\a_{3}b_{1} + a_{3}c_{1} - a_{1}b_{3}-a_{1}c_{3}\\a_{1}b_{2}+a_{1}c_{2} -a_{2}b_{1}-a_{2}c_{1}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{2}b_{3} - a_{3}b_{2}  \\a_{3}b_{1}  - a_{1}b_{3}\\a_{1}b_{2} -a_{2}b_{1}
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}a_2c_3-a_3c_2\\a_3c_1-a_1c_3\\a_1c_2-a_2c_1\end{pmatrix}$$

And this is precisely the RHS.